# injecting through APC using LdrLoadDll fails on `CiValidateImageHeader`

Tags: windows, dll-injection

I've encountered an image validation error while trying to inject dll from
driver which add apc task to be performed by alertable thread. the function task include calling to `LdrLoadDll` with the requested dll to load.

NOTICE: this error occurs only in the latest update (1903)

The injection timing is on creation of new thread on an existing process (so that processes that existed before the driver is loaded could be injected as well - assuming new alertable threads will be created on them).

Anyhow, it seems that although the dll is signed, it fails on signing issue (perhaps mismatch between processes executable file and dll signatures)

here's the stack trace from the context of the injected processes after initial injected code tried to call ldrloaddll

```
[0x0]   CI!CipReportAndReprieveUMCIFailure + 0x563   
[0x1]   CI!CiValidateImageHeader + 0xbdb   
[0x2]   nt!SeValidateImageHeader + 0xd6   
[0x3]   nt!MiValidateSectionCreate + 0x436   
[0x4]   nt!MiValidateSectionSigningPolicy + 0xa6   
[0x5]   nt!MiValidateExistingImage + 0x12e   
[0x6]   nt!MiShareExistingControlArea + 0xc2   
[0x7]   nt!MiCreateImageOrDataSection + 0x1a3   
[0x8]   nt!MiCreateSection + 0xf4   
[0x9]   nt!MiCreateSectionCommon + 0x1ff   
[0xa]   nt!NtCreateSection + 0x60   
[0xb]   nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd + 0x25   
[0xc]   ntdll!NtCreateSection + 0x14   
[0xd]   ntdll!LdrpMapDllNtFileName + 0x136   
[0xe]   ntdll!LdrpMapDllFullPath + 0xe0   
[0xf]   ntdll!LdrpProcessWork + 0x74   
[0x10]   ntdll!LdrpLoadDllInternal + 0x13e   
[0x11]   ntdll!LdrpLoadDll + 0xa8   
[0x12]   ntdll!LdrLoadDll + 0xe4
```

the process is image is spawned from `dllhost.exe` and it's not revealed as protected using method `PsIsProtectedProcess`

Any idea what can lead to this error ?

thanks

Comment: Is there a stats code?

Comment: do you mean error code ? in this case, here's the code `1: kd> !gle
LastErrorValue: (Win32) 0 (0) - The operation completed successfully.
LastStatusValue: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000000d - An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.` doesn't says anything specific ... notice that it happens only in 1903

Comment: try to enable loader snaps